# RegEx for taking product# and Order#

Tags: regex, vba

I am struggling to find a general rule for this, as I newbie in regex domain. I tried a lot of different combinations, but no success. I posted my best one, which still miss some of them.
In abstract, I want to extract order# and Product number in different cells of my array. (global and multi line )

```
for Product #                    [\D^\s]([790]\d{1,4})[\D\s$]  
for Order# (6 or 7 character)    ([56]\d{6})[\D$]|[\D^]([56]\d{5})[\D$]
```

my final pattern for all groups:

```
[\D^\s]([790]\d{1,4})[\D\s$][\D?|^]|([790]\d{1,4})[\D$]|([56]\d{6})[\D$]|[\D?|^]([56]\d{5})[\D$]
```

**these are some examples**

```
5494398 70008                   'order # 5494398  Product#: 70008
5001447452                      ' should be ignored
6415366 OSW SHIP 70052          'order # 6415366  Product#: 70052
6567598y7058 Nov 20             'order # 6567598  Product#: 7058
OSW SHIP 70054 RH STRONGBACKS   'order # N/A      Product#: 70054
OSW HS 70052 70053              'order # N/A      Product#: 70008
6511534 04450                   'order # 6511534  Product#:either  04450 or 0445 (this is only case)
6511538 0046                    'order # 6511538  Product#: 0046
0046 6387125                    'order # 6387125  Product#: 0046
OSW 70032                       'order # N/A      Product#: 70032
OSW HEX Blots 046 047 048 049   'order # N/A      Product#: 064 & 047 & 048 & 049 (4 matches)
```

and this is what i am getting, I think I fail to exactly address the start point and set the length, also not sure why the last product number is not identified! below I posted the test result. I am using this in VBA environment.

Thanks in advance.
M
 [image: Here is the test result I have]

Comment: `[\D$]` is checking of any character that isn't a digit or the `$` sign literally, not the end of line. `[^\D^]` is checking for the same, but `^` literally. It's really confusing, not sure what the rules are and your regex is very wrong.

Comment: In plain English can you explain the rule behind what constitutes and order number and what constitutes a product number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why your regex isn't working

You're confusing quite a few things in your existing regex.

- `[]` this defines a character set. Any positional tokens like `^` or `$` are matched *literally*.

  - `[\D\s$]` matches `\D` (any non-digit character) or `\s` (any whitespace character) or `$` (the dollar sign symbol literally)
  - `[\D?|^]` matches `\D` (any non-digit character) or `?` (question mark symbol literally) or `|` (vertical bar symbol literally) or `^` (carat symbol literally)

Some exceptions to the above are character set specific symbols (and placement usually matters) such as:

- `[^]` any character not in the set - must have carat at the beginning (`[^\d]` any character that isn't in the set - so any non-digit character)
- `[0-9]` any character in the range from `0` to `9` (based on the ASCII table). Lots of times we see people specifying `a-Z` which doesn't match `a-zA-Z`, it matches `[\]^_` and ` as well - see http://www.asciitable.com/)

Instead, use non-capture groups to group those things together. If you need to have positional tokens like `^` or `$` in your regex, include them as alternations `[\d\s]|$` for example.

---

### How to fix your regex

#### Order Number

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/3SQgks/3)

```
(?:^|\D)([790]\d{1,4})(?!\d)
```

The above works as follows:

- `(?:^|\D)` either asserts start of line or matches any non-digit character
- `[790]\d{1,4}` match any character in `790`, then any digit 1-4 more times (matches a 5 digit number starting in 7, 9, or 0)
- `(?!\d)` asserts what follows is not a digit (will also match end of line since it's not a digit)

#### Product Number

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/3SQgks/4)

```
(?:^|\D)[56]\d{5,6}(?!\d)
```

The above works as follows:

- `(?:^|\D)` either asserts start of line or matches any non-digit character
- `[56]\d{5,6}` match any character in `56`, then any digit 5-6 more times (matches a 5 or 6 digit number starting in 5 or 6)
- `(?!\d)` asserts what follows is not a digit (will also match end of line since it's not a digit)

---

### Combining the regex (Final Pattern)

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/3SQgks/6)

```
(?:^|\D)([790]\d{1,4}(?!\d))|(?:^|\D)([56]\d{5,6}(?!\d))
```

The first capture group is order #, the second is product #.

Comment: Awesome reply and great explanation. But I think the way i am taking the groups/ match out is not working. for this 6415366 OSW SHIP 70052  I am seeing following 3 groups: 1)   OSW SHIP70052 2)  OSW SHIP70052 3) 6415366 OSW SHIP   
using `If rgEx.Test(strInput) Then rgEx.Replace(strInput, "$1") , $2 and $3 ` I will try to set the execution on an object and then take them out to see if that is working better.

Comment: there is extra parenthesis in the final pattern, please remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I ***think*** this is what you need:

```
(?<=[^\d]|^)(?<order>[56]\d{5,6})(?=[^\d]|$)|(?<=[^\d]|^)(?<product>[790]\d{1,4})(?=[^\d]|$)
```

I have no clue whether named capture groups such as `?<order>` are supported in VBA. If not then remove the respective `?<order>` and `?<product>` and your matches will be available `$1` and `$2` respectively.

https://regex101.com/r/PeOfKm/1

Comment: Named capture groups don't work in VBA AFAIK, nor do lookbehinds. P.S. `(?<=[^\d]|^)` is the same as `(?<=\D|^)` and can even be simplified as much as `(?<!\d)`; similarly, `(?=[^\d]|$)` to `(?!\d)` :)

Comment: Yes, even after removing named capture groups, it is failing. But you gave me good insight. thanks